# YouTube channel search

Tags: youtube

It appears the YouTube channel search feature has been removed. Example page:

http://youtube.com/channel/UClE2TcmrYlBn4L8WM_fnl_Q

Previously on pages such as this, you would have a search box for video for that
channel only.

- Has it in fact been removed?
- If so, why?
- Is any workaround available to search a channel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a query such as these in the standard YouTube search box. To get
channel videos:

```
intext:"the cinematic orchestra - topic"
```

Channel search:

```
intext:"the cinematic orchestra - topic" everyday
```

Channel search title:

```
intext:"the cinematic orchestra - topic" intitle:everyday
```

Or:

```
"clapham junction" intitle:"warpaint feeling alright"
```

[What Are Google Search Operators?](//moz.com/learn/seo/search-operators)